# What is this little owl-like bird?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology

I was walking outside (location: Netherlands) and just saw this little bird:

[image]
[image]

**Unfortunately I had to take a long range picture with my cell phone so the quality is quite bad**, however I hope still someone can identify this species. Personally I think it escaped somewhere as we have never seen it before and also did not seem to be scared of us.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This looks a lot like a **double-barred finch** ([*Taeniopygia bichenovii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barred_finch)). Your note about this being an "owl-like" bird is supported by it's less common name, the "owl finch", so named for the dark ring around the face.

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamant_de_Bicheno#/media/Fichier:Double-barred_Finch.jpg); Credit: Glen Fergus</sup>

If this is in fact the bird you saw, you're right that it's not native to your country (or continent or even hemisphere!). The [*Taeniopygia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taeniopygia) genus is in the [Estrildidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estrildidae) family, and it only contains two species native *to Australia*! According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barred_finch), *T. bichenovii* is found:

> in dry savannah, tropical (lowland) dry grassland and shrubland habitats in northern and eastern Australia

You can read more at [eFinch](http://www.efinch.com/species/owl.htm) and [The Atlas iof Living Australia](https://bie.ala.org.au/species/urn:lsid:biodiversity.org.au:afd.name:56012fdd-c351-4216-8754-30a352366397).

Comment: @KingBoomie If there are any zoos in your area, you may want to give them a call to ask if they are missing this little fellow.

Comment: @AndrewKozak good idea; also any local pet stores that sell exotic birds. Could be one of their customers has lost a pet!

Comment: Public aviaries (volière in Dutch) are also a possibility.  Most exotic birds are not on the list of allowed pets in the Netherlands and although uncommon, aviaries are more common than zoos.

Comment: @AndrewKozak  Probably from a public aviary, while it had a ring there was no number on it so we gave it to a relative having birds himself and he would figure our where to bring the little fellow ;)